# Why is the sigh at one point enough to determine the orientation of the whole pullback itself?

Tags: differential-forms

I was reading a textbook on differential form and it said finding the value at one point is enough to determine the orientation of the whole parameter plane at all point.

EDIT:
The example they give is the sphere parameterized by

$ x=cos\theta\, cos \phi $

$ y=sin\theta\, cos\phi $

$ z=sin\phi $

for $ dy\wedge dz $ compute the pull back

$ dy= cos\theta\,cos\phi\, d\theta\,-sin\theta\,sin\phi\, d\phi$

$ dz=cos\phi \,d\phi  $

$dy \wedge dz=cos\theta\,cos^2\phi \,d \theta \wedge d\phi $

and since $ x\,dy \wedge dz $ must be positive for

$[     -\frac \pi2\le \phi \le \frac \pi2 \,,\,0 \le\theta\le2\pi] $

so

$ cos^2\theta\,cos^3\phi\, d\theta \wedge d\phi\ge0 $

leave $ d\theta\ \wedge d\phi$ positive so the orientation is                  $ d\theta \wedge d\phi $ as orientation of $ dy\wedge dz $

but it also say that we can know the orientation by just evaluating at one point (1,0,0) and the pull back become $ 1\times cos(0)\times cos^2(0)=1 $ so  $ d\theta\ \wedge d\phi$ positive oriented same as $ dy\wedge dz $.

What I don't understand is why this work and does for all parameterized surface(i.e. : a torus).

(sorry about the choice of word I'm only reading this as a hobby so don't quite really understand the term a proper mathematician might used)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. "Finding the value at one point" of _what_? What is "the orientation of the whole parameter plane" supposed to mean? When you say "the whole pullback," what are you pulling back, and by what map?

Comment: I will say, though, that I like the image evoked by "the sigh at one point." <sigh>